# Android - Jsoup.connect().get()

Tags: android, jsoup

I am new with using jsoup and I just want to ask if must I use the jsoup codes inside public static void main as I've seen on the web on my research or can I use it inside any other method. Also I am having a problem with Jsoup.connect().get(). My application always stops when I run it. I already added android.permission.Internet to my AndroidManifest.xml. I read the cookbook and decided to start with parsing a document and I still generate the same result - Unfortunately, application has stopped. My minsdkversion is 8 and my targetsdkversion is 15. Please bear with me.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Jsoup_2 extends Activity{
static String website_url = "http://www.google.com";

/**
 * @param args
 */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jsoupactivity);

    try{
         Document doc = Jsoup.connect(website_url).get();
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.label)).setText("Loading website");
    }catch (Exception e){
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.label)).setText("error");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're running this code in the main thread. You have to put in an AsyncTask or another new Thread...never execute heavy operations on the main thread (e.g. onCreate() method).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_jsoupactivity);

new AsyncTask(String,Integer,Document) {
  public Document doInBackground(String... params) {
   Document doc = null;
   try{
     doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();

    }catch (Exception e){
     doc = null;
    }

 return doc;
  }

 public void onPostExecute(Document result) {
   if (result != null) {
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.label)).setText("Loading website");
   } else {
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.label)).setText("Error");
   }
  }

}.execute(website_url);}}
```

Comment: please share the results for contributing with other users.

Answer (score 0):

**lightweight**

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_jsoupactivity);
       final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);

       new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               String str;
               try {
                   Document doc = Jsoup.connect(website_url).get();
                   str = "";
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   str = ",";
               }
               final String finalStr = str;
               tv.post(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                      tv.setText(finalStr);
                  }
              });
          }
      }).start();
```

}